# SQL replace bullet points

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and need to replace bullet points with a hyphen.

I have data in a table (tblJobs) that looks like the below:

```
• Renew kitchen
```

If I paste this into Notepad ++ and change the encoding to ANSI I get the below:

```
â€¢ Renew kitchen
```

How do I replace the '•' to a '-'?

This is my SQL:

```
Select RTRIM (REPLACE ([JobDesc],'â€¢', '-')) as Notes
From tblJobs
```

However, the bullet points are still coming through.

What am I missing?

Comment: `'â€¢'`isn't a bullet point. A bullet point is the `'•'` character.

Comment: REPLACE replaces one string with another. You need some kind of REGEXP_REPLACE .

Comment: try with putting `N` in front of bullet string, like `Select RTRIM (REPLACE(Notes, N'â€¢', '-')) as Notes`

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE ('â€¢ point 1 â€¢ point 2 â€¢ point 3 â€¢ point 4','â€¢','-')` works for me; are we *missing* something here?

Comment: @Larnu I thought the REPLACE function only excepts 2 arguments?

Comment: No, @Michael. [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). `REPLACE` replaces **all** occurrences of the second parameter with the third, within the first parameter. So `REPLACE('abcdefg abcdef','cd','q')` would return `'abqefd abqefd'`.

Comment: @Larnu my bad - I missed out the field name ; -p I have edited original question

Comment: @Nino this does not work I'm afraid, still coming through as bullet points

Comment: what datatype is the column? varchar or nvarchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actual access to the data, it is hard to tell what that bullet actually is.  There are a lot of 'bullet' symbols it seems (sort of like how many different kinds of quotes there are!)  Could be a lot of things.  However I've done a little bit of playing and maybe this will help you:

````
--hm! this works, but we are not starting with a bullet
DECLARE @DATA_1 VARCHAR(50)
SET @DATA_1 = 'â€¢ Renew kitchen'
SELECT RTRIM (REPLACE (@DATA_1,'â€¢', '-')) as TEST_1

--basically the problem you are seeing, the bullet is getting flipped into a set of characters
DECLARE @DATA_2 VARCHAR(50)
SET @DATA_2 = '• Renew kitchen' 
SELECT RTRIM (REPLACE (@DATA_1,'•', '-')) as TEST_2

--ok, let's just double translate it?
DECLARE @DATA_3 VARCHAR(50)
SET @DATA_3 = '• Renew kitchen'

DECLARE @DATA_4 VARCHAR(50)
SET @DATA_4 = RTRIM (REPLACE (@DATA_3,'•', '-')) 

SELECT RTRIM (REPLACE (@DATA_4,'â€¢', '-')) as TEST_3```
````

This yields the following results.

[image]

Hopefully this will do the trick for you, looks like it produces what you are looking for.  The bullet I'm using is the one copy/pasted from the question.  You could also just nest the replaces, I wrote the above so it better shows the thought process.

Answer (score 0):

hyphen bullet is a Unicode symbol and has DEC number 8259.
Look at my example below:

```
declare @b as nchar(50) = nchar(8259);
select @b, replace(@b, nchar(8259), '-')
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is using `⁃` and not `•` (or even `∙` or `◦`).

Comment: Agree. so just use my sample as an example and adjust it according to requirements

Comment: @Michael do you have replaced my nchar(8259) with your symbols?